# How to show breadcrumbs on my pages in magento?

Tags: magento, breadcrumbs

I want to display the breadcrumbs on 1column.phtml pages.
I tried the following

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock("breadcrumbs")->toHtml()?>
```

But it gives me the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object
```

So what should I do for displaying the breadcrumbs on my pages?

Comment: I was also stucked !!! I am newbie in magento 1.7.0.2 !!! I didn't know how to show breadcrumb on pages !!! you solved my problem !!! thank you very very much !!

Answer (score 1):

This question is raised and solved in many forums.I think this will work for you

File path

> \app\design\frontend\default\themename\layout\page.xml

Find

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml"/>
```

Replace with

```
<block type="core/profiler" output="toHtml" name="core_profiler"/>
```